# Add empty row if the condition is false

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

Given the dataframe below:

```
 Row|Address_StoreHours_Phone_RemoveHrTag|
+---+------------------------------------+
|  1|                Ph 148-01 Metro P...|
|  2|                Store Hours: 7:00...|
|  3|                <hr class="dashed"/>|
|  4|                Ground Floor Vict...|
|  5|                       +632-82833778|
|  6|                        Store Hours:|
|  7|                <hr class="dashed"/>|
|  8|                Phase 1 Package 1...|
|  9|                       +632-83722847|
| 10|                Store Hours: 7:00...|
| 11|                <hr class="dashed"/>|
```

How do i add empty row 1 row above hr class="dashed"/ if hr class="dashed"/'s row is not divisible by 4, e.g.

```
 Row|Address_StoreHours_Phone_RemoveHrTag|
+---+------------------------------------+
|  1|                Ph 148-01 Metro P...|
|  2|                                    |
|  3|                Store Hours: 7:00...|
|  4|                <hr class="dashed"/>|
|  5|                Ground Floor Vict...|
|  6|                       +632-82833778|
|  7|                        Store Hours:|
|  8|                <hr class="dashed"/>|
|  9|                Phase 1 Package 1...|
| 10|                       +632-83722847|
| 11|                Store Hours: 7:00...|
| 12|                <hr class="dashed"/>|
```

Here's what i've done so far, hr_tag column returns true if hr class="dashed"/ is in row divisible by 4

```
spark.sql("""
    WITH create_row AS(
        SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS INTEGER) AS Row, *
        FROM ssd_others
    ), filter_hr_tag AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            CASE
                WHEN `Address_StoreHours_Phone_RemoveHrTag` = '<hr class="dashed"/>' AND `Row` % 4 = 0
                THEN True
                ELSE False
            END AS hr_tag
        FROM create_row
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM filter_hr_tag
""")
```

and here's the code's output

```
Row|Address_StoreHours_Phone_RemoveHrTag|hr_tag|
+---+------------------------------------+------+
|  1|                Ph 148-01 Metro P...| false|
|  2|                Store Hours: 7:00...| false|
|  3|                <hr class="dashed"/>| false|
|  4|                Ground Floor Vict...| false|
|  5|                       +632-82833778| false|
|  6|                        Store Hours:| false|
|  7|                <hr class="dashed"/>| false|
|  8|                Phase 1 Package 1...| false|
|  9|                       +632-83722847| false|
| 10|                Store Hours: 7:00...| false|
| 11|                <hr class="dashed"/>| false|
```

Comment: It sounds like you are doing report formatting in.... spark? Thats a curious choice. I think the first step to solving this is finding the row number - do you have existing code that does that? This site works better when you post what you've already tried, to give us some context on where you are at.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i wanted to transform data, i figured i have 3 choices - pandas, or  load it in sqlite and transform data in there, or pyspark and use spark sql. Pysparks seems to be the best choice since it's a very common tool for data engineering and this data transformation is a good opportunity for me to practice on it. Btw, i've also made some edits!

Comment: Notice you are writing SQL in Spark? So why not just use SQL? Where is this data from and where is it going? Is it for a report?

Answer (score 1):

I can't do it with spark, so my workaround here is just to use python's list

```
ssd_row = ssd_cleaning.select("Row").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
ssd_other_info = ssd_cleaning.select("Address_StoreHours_Phone_RemoveHrTag").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

ssd_list = [list(x) for x in zip(ssd_row, ssd_other_info)]

for row in ssd_list:
    if row[1] == '<hr class="dashed"/>' and row[0] % 4 != 0:
        new_empty_row = [row[0] - 1.5,""]
        ssd_list.append(new_empty_row) 
        ssd_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
        for index,x in enumerate(ssd_list):
            ssd_list[index][0] = index+1

reordered_data_distribution_cleaning_ssd = spark.createDataFrame(ssd_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by

1. Identify when an empty row has to be added.
2. If for every row, the succedding row contains `add_empty_row`, then convert `Address_StoreHours_Phone_RemoveHrTag` to an array of a empty string and then `Address_StoreHours_Phone_RemoveHrTag`.
3. Finally explode the column from step 2 and recompute the row number.

> Window functions without `partitionBy` move all data into a single partition degrading performance. I assume given your use in the code snippet in question this is acceptable.

```py
data = [(1, 'Ph 148-01 Metro P...'),
        (2, 'Store Hours: 7:00...'),
        (3, '<hr class="dashed"/>',),
        (4, 'Ground Floor Vict...'),
        (5, '+632-82833778",',),
        (6, 'Store Hours:'),
        (7, '<hr class="dashed"/>',),
        (8, 'Phase 1 Package 1...'),
        (9, '+632-83722847",',),
        (10, 'Store Hours: 7:00...'),
        (11, '<hr class="dashed"/>',), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Row", "Address_StoreHours_Phone_RemoveHrTag", ))

df.createOrReplaceTempView("create_row")

query = """
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY `row`, length(`address_storehours_phone_removehrtag`)) as `row`,
       EXPLODE(CASE
                   WHEN add_empty_row THEN array("", `address_storehours_phone_removehrtag`)
                   ELSE array(`address_storehours_phone_removehrtag`)
               END) AS `address_storehours_phone_removehrtag`
FROM
  (SELECT `row`,
          `address_storehours_phone_removehrtag`,
          LEAD(add_empty_row, 1, FALSE) OVER (
                                              ORDER BY `row`) AS add_empty_row
   FROM
     (SELECT *,
             CASE
                 WHEN `address_storehours_phone_removehrtag` = '<hr class="dashed"/>'
                      AND `row` % 4 != 0 AND `row` % 4 = `row` THEN TRUE
                 ELSE FALSE
             END AS add_empty_row
      FROM create_row) t) w
"""


spark.sql(query).show()


"""
+---+------------------------------------+
|row|address_storehours_phone_removehrtag|
+---+------------------------------------+
|  1|                Ph 148-01 Metro P...|
|  2|                                    |
|  3|                Store Hours: 7:00...|
|  4|                <hr class="dashed"/>|
|  5|                Ground Floor Vict...|
|  6|                     +632-82833778",|
|  7|                        Store Hours:|
|  8|                <hr class="dashed"/>|
|  9|                Phase 1 Package 1...|
| 10|                     +632-83722847",|
| 11|                Store Hours: 7:00...|
| 12|                <hr class="dashed"/>|
+---+------------------------------------+
"""
```

Comment: My first attempt was actually very similar to this, but what i need is for the row count to be reordered at every empty row to be added or else an empty row just like in row 7 at your output would appear, in conclusion - i have to traverse to each of the row then add an empty row if filtered_hr_tag is true then reorder the row count everytime i appended an empty row. What i'm really trying to do is to make sure there are exactly 3 rows above at every hr class="dashed"/ to even out the data distribution, purpose of this is so i could convert these rows into its corresponding column.

Comment: @RenzCarillo so you need to need add rows to make all subsequent `<hr class="dashed"/>` to be divisible by 4?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i'm trying

Comment: @RenzCarillo can yoiu confirm if the row number(row containing  `<hr class="dashed"/>`) % 4 would be the same throughout your dataset? Meaning adding a couple of empty at the top would fix all subsequent rows

Comment: Yes, it would. There are thousands of data that only has 2 rows above the <hr class="dashed"/> and for some there are 3, it is those that only has 2 rows above that needs to be fixed

Comment: I have editing my answers to reflect this, note the answer is not generic and will work only if the row number of  first instance of `<hr class="dashed"/>` = 3, the idea can be extrapolated to make it generic, esentially figure out the first instance of `<hr class="dashed"/>` that needs fixing and finds its row number and make it as part of the condition.